# ExpressionEngine CustomCSS | Generating an empty style tag

Tags: css

Cutting right to the chase: I'm needing to enable Custom CSS on a particular entry.

[image: Current CSS Configuration]

Whenever I load the page and inspect in Dev Tools, The style tag that Expression Engine promises to "automatically generate" is completely empty.  It looks like this:
[image: Current Page Source]

What do I need to do to get ExpressionEngine to push my class definitions into that darn style tag?

Comment: Is that an add-on or just a normal textarea custom field?

Comment: I think it's just a "normal textarea custom field." I enabled it on the page by showing the toolbar, by clicking the eyelid next to "Custom CSS" to make the icon an open eye. Then I saved the Layout and added CSS to the "Custom CSS" section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response above, it sounds like this custom field hasn't been implemented in your templates. Go to Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Fields to find the variable name for this field. Then go to Design > Template Manager and type the variable's name into the search field. That will show you which templates, if any, it's on, which should let you drill down further.

What you will likely be looking for, depending on how the person who built the site implemented it, is something like this (assuming the variable name `custom_css`):

```
{if custom_css != ''}
    <style type="text/css">{custom_css}</style>
{/if}
```

Keep in mind that this is might be a different location from the site's main style tag, which is probably defined in a layout or embedded template that is used site-wide for the `<head>` section of your HTML.